# How to fire buttons events(down,up) at the same time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have 2 buttons for 2 user means each user have its own button. User have two events button down and button up.I want to Find Which user's button up event fired first.

I used tk2d for perform those things. But main problem is that When 1st user press own button down then after 2nd user press its own button down at that same time 1st users button automatically button up so how can i solve this problem.Means that both user cant press button down in this situation.

I want both user can fired its own button down and up both event whatever he/she want.

Is this possible and if so, how can I handle this?

Thanking To You.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "perform button down."

If you mean "click both buttons at once" then you need a means to do that: I'm guessing you're looking at a touch input device that will accept multiple presses at once. 

If you mean "call the code that happens when I click two different buttons at the same time" then the solution is to move that code out of a "button click" and into a separate method that you can call from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

try this (in JavaScript)

```
#pragma strict


function Update () {

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) {
// do something
}   

}
```

something like this might work, because in the update, it will check if both the mouse button and space bar are down in that update cycle, then you do something.

hope that helps